# YAGNI vs Program to interfaces rather than concrete implementations

Tags: oop, design-patterns, refactoring, solid-principles, ooad

YAGNI (You aren't going to need it) rule says we should the minimum number of elements in our code to do the job.

But whenever I create a class it's recommended that we should first create an interface then extend it by having a child class as per principle "Program to interfaces rather than concrete implementations" so that I can accommodate future requirements better and have more loosely coupled code.

But according to YAGNI, from the beginning, we should avoid creating unnecessary interfaces.

So which to follow and when to follow?

Answer (score 0):

From Martin Fowler's [bliki](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html),

> **Yagni only applies to capabilities built into the software to support a presumptive feature, it does not apply to effort to make the software easier to modify.**

In general, programming to abstractions falls into the latter category.

Comment: IMHO, too little attention is paid to the "imagine the refactoring" issue alluded to the article, especially the question of *who would need to do it*.  If adding a feature later would require changes to modules that are maintained by different people, that may be slightly annoying but tolerable if applications not requiring the feature would continue to work if one module were upgraded and the other not, but it would be very bad if it required that two modules had to be changed in ways which would make them incompatible with older versions of each other.  One should work hard...

Comment: ...to make enough preparations for future changes that one can avoid the latter situation if at all possible.  Allowing features to be added merely by changing code that's under the control of a single person would be better than requiring coordination, but what's most important is allowing the changes to be made in a way that allows each module to remain compatible with older versions of the other.